# Do not allow not logged in user to access a jsp page in Liferay

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay

I have a.jsp in webapps folder of lieray projec. I want to restrict not logged in and not admin users to acces the page. How to do that?

Comment: You can only access something in liferay through a renderURL or actionURL or resourceURL. So unless you have constructed these in your portlet project and mapped it to your JSP you cannot access the JSP directly. So can you add more detail to your question and some code?

Comment: you can check by themeDisplay object if user is logged in or not and if user is logged in ,he is admin or not by themeDisplay.isSignedIn() and permissionChecker.isOmniadmin(). HTH

Comment: @PrakashK, I have a create_account.jsp in Liferay hook and I need to restrict user to access this page if he/she is not logged in and is not admin.

Comment: problem is if user inputs the getURL string from browser "http://localhost:8080/web/account?p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_mode=view&saveLastPath=0&_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Fcreate_account" can go to this page. So I want to restrict this page only to logged in user. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If am correct you want the page view to be restricted from guest users.
You can achieve this by using - permissionChecker.ischeckGuest()

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if(request.isUserInRole("Administrator")&&request.isUserInRole("User"))
{
    //shwow the content you wnat this kind of users to see
} else {
        show the content that not authorized users to see
       }
```

They can still access the page but they will not see the content that is not for them.
If you see the page source from the browser you cannot find the code that admins and other users can see which is good for security reasons.

I hope that helped!